# How to convert list('92589492','92589494','92589495') to rows in PostgresSQL? Transpose?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Convert List like ('92589491','92589492','92589493') as row in PostgreSQL?

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(
 '92589491','92589492','92589493'
)
 AS t(col)

ColumnName
92589491
92589492
92589493
92589494
```

Comment: What is the data type of this list?  What does the query have to do with the results?

Comment: i will pass comma separated list as varchar @GordonLinoff

Comment: sorry i changed it please check @JNevill

Comment: . . In Postgres, you should be passing such values as arrays.

Comment: Sounds like a task for `regexp_split_to_table`.